# Java: two threads summing numbers in a given range simultaneously: when just one thread is joined the second thread's sum is too big

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I  have two threads that sum values in a single array of integers: `[0; 100_000]`.
Each thread is an object that has `min, max` and `sum` fields and I later get the total sum by summing the result of both threads. 
Thread 1 sums numbers in `[0, 20_000]` range, while thread 2 sums numbers in `[20_001, 100_000]` range. The correct thread1's sum is `200,010,000`, the correct thread2's sum is `505,072,704`, the correct total sum of numbers in `[0, 100_000]` range is `705,082,704`.

It works fine when both threads are joined inside the main method's thread. However if I only join the first thread, the main method proceeds to print the results before the second thread is finished. I understand this behavior. However, I don't understand why in those results (at which point thread1's finished and its sum is correct, while thread2 is not finished yet and its sum is not correct) the thread2's sum exceeds the maximum possible sum for it (`505,072,704`). I don't understand how it's possible.

```
public class SumNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100_000;

        int left = 20_000;
        int right = 100_000;

        int usualSum = 0;
        for (int i = min; i<= max; i++)  {
            usualSum += i;
        }
        System.out.printf("usual sum: %,d\n", usualSum);

        SummerThread s1 = new SummerThread(0, left);
        SummerThread s2 = new SummerThread(left + 1, right);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(s1, "left thread");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(s2, "right thread");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
       // thread2.join();

        System.out.printf("left sum: %,d\n", s1.getSum());
        System.out.printf("right sum: %,d\n", s2.getSum());
        System.out.printf("left + right: %,d\n", s1.getSum() + s2.getSum());

        thread2.join();
        System.out.printf("right sum: %,d\n", s2.getSum());
        System.out.printf("left + right: %,d\n", s1.getSum() + s2.getSum());

    }
}

class SummerThread implements Runnable  {


    private int sum;
    private int min;
    private int max;

    private int id;
    private static int count;

    public SummerThread(int min, int max)  {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

        count++;
        id = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)  {
           // System.out.println("thread: " + id);
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    public int getSum()  {return sum;}
}
```

The output is different accross the runs:

```
usual sum: 705,082,704
left sum: 200,010,000
right sum: 645,520,003
left + right: 1,020,729,153
right sum: 505,072,704
left + right: 705,082,704
```

```
usual sum: 705,082,704
left sum: 200,010,000
right sum: 168,890,703
left + right: 1,049,163,528
right sum: 505,072,704
left + right: 705,082,704
```

```
usual sum: 705,082,704
left sum: 200,010,000
right sum: 1,625,006,320
left + right: 1,825,016,320
right sum: 505,072,704
left + right: 705,082,704
```

The **correct** output (if all `.join` are uncommented) is:

```
usual sum: 705,082,704
left sum: 200,010,000
right sum: 505,072,704
left + right: 705,082,704
right sum: 505,072,704
left + right: 705,082,704
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't your maths off here? The sum from 1 to n is `n(n+1)/2`, which, if you replace `n` with `100,000`, gives you `5,000,050,000`. This exceeds the maximum number you can store in an `int`, which is about 2 billion. The reason why the partial sum is higher than the final sum is likely because you experienced an integer overflow.

To illustrate this, the snippet below is useful:

```
System.out.println((int) 5_000_050_000L); // prints 705082704
```

As you can see, we find your 705,082,704 sum again, but it is incorrect and only results from the integer overlow.

Comment: Thank you! I totally didn't realize the correct sum is actually different! I replaced all `int` with `long`

Comment: No prob. To make the code a little safer, you could do something like `if (sum > Long.MAX_VALUE - i) throw ...` in your loop, that way you defend against overflows

Comment: `StrictMath.addExact(x, y)` might be better.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this